# Mean value theorem understanding

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I have this question here which says:

Say that f is differentiable and $f'(x)\neq1$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$. Show that there is at most one real number $a$ such that $f(a)=a$

I'm supposed to use the mean value theorem with the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ but i'm not really sure how I'm supposed to incorporated the mean value theorem into this...

I tried to substitute for $f(b)$ with $g(b)+b$ and simplify things but i'm not getting anywhere.

Any help on this please?

Comment: Please type your question using MathJax. Surely, we can read the question, but search won't be able to. The very point of SE is to make database of questions and answers that can serve as a reference in future. Your question doesn't add to it, as it is now.

Comment: Sure. Give me a moment.

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: Appreciated. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary there are two distinct values such that $f(a)=a$, and $f(b)=b$.

The defining $g(x)=f(x)-x$, we get $g(a)=0$ and $g(b)=0$.

By Mean Value Theorem (Note $g$ is also differentiable):

$g'(c)=\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}=0$ for some $c$ between $a$ and $b$.

This means $0=g'(c)=f'(c)-1$, so $f'(c)=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: That was much easier than I thought it would be. Thank you very much haha.

Comment: It seems to me very counter-intuitive that the derivative of $g$ doesn't need to be continuous. Suppose $g'(x) = -1$ for $x \leq 0$, $g'(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $g(0)=0$. Wouldn't this result in $g(-1)=g(1)=1$ without the derivative of $g$ every being $0$?

Comment: @dimpol : Your $g$ would require that $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.  The derivative of a differentiable function cannot have a jump discontinuity (although other discontinuities are possible).

Answer (score 7):

It is not necessary to consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$.

Suppose that there are $a,b \in \mathbb R$ such that $b>a$,  $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$. Then

$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=1 \ne f'(c)$ for all $c \in (a,b)$, a contadiction